# Рефакторинг

Tags: php

Написал не очень хорошо, прошу подсказать более правильное решение, код подключает шаблон:

```
<?php
defined('MEX') or die("Нет доступа");
class View extends setting
{
    public static function Factory($view, $title, $data)
    {
       $file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/views/view_'.$view.'.php';
       if(!file_exists($file))
       {
          engine :: NotFound();
       }
       else
       {
           extract($data);
           ob_start();
           include_once $file;
           $content = ob_get_contents();
           ob_end_clean();

           ob_start();
           include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/views/BASIC.php';
           $view = ob_get_contents();
           ob_end_clean();
           echo $view;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**upd:**

```
ob_start();
  include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/views/BASIC.php';
  $view = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  echo $view;
```

можно просто заменить на:

```
       include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/views/BASIC.php';
```

а

```
 $content = ob_get_contents();
 ob_end_clean();
```

на

```
$content = ob_get_clean();
```

Answer (score 0):

Зачем буферизация? Записывайте код в переменную.

Comment: Мне что-то подсказывает, что там нативные шаблоны. Т.е. вы запишете в переменнукю php-код. И @FLK тоже.

..иначе зачем `extract($data)`, шоб было?

Comment: @Sh4dow угу согласен поспешил я с выводами.