# Как переместить HTML-страницу в переменную PHP?

Tags: php, html

Для содержания в php переменной HTML текста нужно для кавычек добавлять косую черту, а вот забыла функцию для конвертирования из HTML в PHP, просто нужно HTML страницу полностью поместить в переменную PHP. Спасибо.

Comment: Еще один считающий, что девушкам в интернете быстрее помогают :)  

    $php= <<< HEREDOC
    HTML page
    HEREDOC;
    $php='I have mod more """ '; // а вот так не нужно экранировать кавычки, зато надо экранировать апострофы.
А еще лучше прочитать что-нибудь про основы языка.
    

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php

Comment: @ReinRaus тот же :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По поводу кавычек [читайте](http://i-novice.net/magicheskie-kavychki-magic-quotes-v-php-i-ekranirovanie/). А вообще [сюда.](http://www.php.ru/)

Comment: Вы и правда думаете что тут читаю люди? =)

Comment: А Бог их знает :) Во всяком случае - пара-тройка извилин у отдельных личностей есть.

Answer (score 2):

[htmlspecialchars](http://ua.php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php) - вроде нужная Вам функция.

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = <<<HERE
  ТУТ Html документ
here;
```

Обратите внимание пробел после `<<<HERE` или перед `here;`, не должен быть, иначе будет ошибка.
**Дополнение** 
Для того чтобы экранизировать символы в переменной можно использовать функцию `mysql_escape_string`. Пример использования:

```
  $a = <<<HERE
          ТУТ Html документ
        here;
    $a = mysql_escape_string($a);
```

ReinRaus, =))

Comment: а вот была же какая то функция по переводу, специально для хранения а БД...ни кто случайно не помнит?

Comment: Вы хотите код html хранить в базе данных?

Comment: Я вроде не просила задавать вопросы, я сама задаю. Пожалуйста, выручите кто нибудь

Comment: Вы интересная личность, как я могу Вам помочь если Вы не уточнили что Вам нужно... И кстати на Ваш вопрос уже дан ответ( на первый вопрос)

Comment: Мне нужно функция для добавления слешов, чтобы злой дядька "БД" не ругал меня за то что бывает попадаются ковычки

Comment: @node_pro, опять вопросы задаете. Нужны только ответы.

Comment: `addslashes()` вот такая функция есть пойдет Вам? А вообще чтобы успешное добавление в базу данных есть функция: `mysql_escape_string()`

Comment: @ReinRaus, скажите уважаемый, если Вам понятна была проблема с началу почему вместо того чтобы меня поучать, сами не ответили? А в места того пишите в данном ситуации флуд.

Comment: @node_pro, я смайлик в конце того сообщения забыл поставить. Извините.  
А что хочет автор вопроса я тоже изначально не понимал :(  
Виноват я в-общем. Прошу понять, простить.

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string()?

Comment: Для того чтобы экранизировать символы в переменной можно использовать функцию mysql_escape_string? О да, это гениально

Comment: @Node_pro Вот то что нужно) спасибо большое Вам addslashes именно то, что я искала)

Answer (score 0):

Пишем свой html в файл, например `superCoolPage.html`, допустим сохраняем в папку `static` в корне сайта, потом читаем его содержимое:

```
$html = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/static/superCoolPage.html');
// profit
```

---

@johniek_comp - лимит комментариев. Гоню здесь не я, "подростешь" поймешь.

Улыбнуло -  вбил в поиск hashcode DOCUMENT_ROOT - [четвертый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/95627/%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3) ваш

Comment: $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] не кроссплатформенно, кури dir ИМХО

Comment: Нужно быть мудаком, что бы использовать $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

Comment: @VasyOk - соизвольте обосновать, в вашем быдло предложении я не увидел аргументов.

Вот вы, на пару с @johniek_comp пишите о том, что это **очень плохо**, но я так и не увидел **ни единого обоснования**. Я спрашиваю - что в этом плохого? Но, судя по всему, получить ответ - не судьба.

Comment: @AlexWindHope, не принято использоваться глобальные переменные.
1. Её можно переопределить
2. Не все серверы её правильно определяют.
3. Не красивый код

Comment: @VasyOk - для особо одаренных:

 - я ничего не переопределял, для того, что-бы пример был максимально простым

 - не слышал об этом

 - это, в целом, так или иначе, можно отнести к первому пункту, к тому-же - это ваше сугубо личное мнение.


Пример, где DOCUMENT_ROOT не работает будет или нет? Или вы чисто полялякать? :)


'не принято использоваться глобальные переменные'? Т.е вы хотите сказать, что вы не используете, глобальные переменные _POST, _GET, _COOKIE, _SESSION? "Если" таки да - чем _SERVER хуже остальных?

Comment: Слышал есть проблема на windows хостингах, если не ошибаюсь из-за слеша в конце все отваливается. Использую все перечисленные вами переменные и те которые вы забыли упомянуть. Но к переменной $_SERVER отношусь как источнику дополнительной информации и использовать её тоже нужно с умом. А по поводу вашего "сугубо личное мнение": Код нужно писать так что бы за него не было стыдно. Я, например, не хотел бы после вас дорабатывать/править проекты. Вы слишком похуестично относитесь к деталям.

Comment: @VasyOk - я вас понял, вы их тех, кто прочитав какую-то инфу из псевдо-авторитетного источника - свято принимает ее на веру и с пеной у рта доказывает "единожды верное мнение".

'если не ошибаюсь из-за слеша в конце все отваливается' - если не ошибаюсь - это тяжело назвать примером, у меня все всегда работало как под виндой так и под никсами, соответственно здесь проблема кривых рук, а не DOCUMENT_ROOT.

Мне, за этот код абсолютно не стыдно, не могли-бы вы продемонстрировать мастер класс и показать - как бы вы переписали этот код?

###### ...после вас дорабатывать/править проекты... - взаимно

Comment: Поддерживаю. Хочу увидеть мастер-класс.

Comment: В те далекие времена, когда я еще только начинал, я делал сайты на denver`е. Значительно наебался во время деплоя каждого проекта. Там же и набил руку.

А ваш код я написал бы через fopen используя __DIR__, __FILE__, dirname, realpath и тд и пт. Поэту если переносить или менять архитектуру проекта или использоваться код под cli у меня будет все работать. 

В общем то коллеги не жалуются на мой код :)

Comment: @VasyOk.  

    Использование функции file_get_contents() наиболее предпочтительно в случае необходимости получить содержимое файла целиком, поскольку для улучшения производительности функция использует технику отображения файла в память (memory mapping), если она поддерживается вашей операционной системой.

Comment: я же написал сразу это не кроссплатформенно, проще использовать dir как я выше описал, в чем проблемы? чего гонишь, @AlexWindHope

Comment: - К чему вообще был написан первый абзац? Вы думаете кому-то это интересно?

 - зачем `fopen`? Вы вообще понимаете что делает эта функция и что делает `file_get_contents`?
 
 - 'коллеги не жалуются на мой код', возможно вас это удивит, но - аналогично. Представляю уровень ваших коллег...

 - 'Вы слишком похуестично относитесь к деталям' - как скажете, о великий :D

К тому-же:

 - `__DIR__` **определенно** !== `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

 - "если переносить или менять архитектуру или использоваться код под cli???" Вы издеваетесь?

 В общем - с этого и нужно было начинать ваш "мастер-класс"

Answer (score 0):

```
  $page = file_get_contents('http://ссылка.com');
```

Ваша страница, указанная между кавычками, будет содержаться в виде HTML-текста (кода) в переменной $page.